Why can't I use more Servlets in JAVA EE?
I have the following situation: I am working on a project where I initially used 3 servlets and everything worked great, the problem was when I tried to create a fourth servert. For some reason that I have not been able to understand, no JSP wanted to connect with that last servlet (the classic HTTP Status 404 - Not found: The required resource [...] is not available appears), it connects with any of the other three, and with their respective GET and POST, thus demonstrating that the problem is not in Apache Tomcat, but it simply does not do so with this room. It should be noted that I have verified it and indeed I have no writing errors. I don't know if there is some limitation on the number of servlet options that are allowed to be used, so my project is limited to a maximum of three servlets, or if it is some other kind of problem. As a development environment I am using NetBeans.
I've tried deleting the fourth servlet and recreating it, and I've also tried invoking it in a different JSP, however the same thing happens.
Below is the JSP it is called from.
<h1>Iniciar sesion</h1><br>
<% String mensaje = request.getParameter("mensajeError");
    if(mensaje == null){
        mensaje="";
    }

%>

<form action="SvLoggin" method="POST">
<div class="form">
<label>Usuario</label><br>
<input type="text" id="user" name="usuario"><br>
<label>Contraseña</label><br>
<input type="password" id="pass" name="contraseña"><br>
<div id="verificacion"><p><%=mensaje%></p></div>
<button onclick="" class="button"> Inicio </button><br>
</div>
</form>

and this is the servlet
public class SvLoggin extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet SvLoggin</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet SvLoggin at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}

but the result is
enter image description here
**this is the web.xml
**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
   version="6.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>

thanks

I looks like your Servlets are not registered in web.xml meaning they are done with code or properties. https://www.baeldung.com/register-servlet
Either search the project for the path of one of the working 3 Servlets and copy/paste/modify or simply add to web.xml like this https://www.baeldung.com/register-servlet#2-xml-configuration. It’s the common way of registering Servlets.

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/78726291/573032

There are no software limits. You're just not running the code you think you're running.

@JohnWilliams. Thank you very much, that was the problem, now I was able to connect said servlet. Blessings!
